# Runtime created checkbox loses style

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I'm a newbie to android development, making my first app.

I have a list of objects and need to make a bunch of checkboxes inside another view dynamically using this list, so I'm doing the following:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.product_check_list);
ProductHelper helper = new ProductHelper(getApplicationContext());
List<Product> products = helper.getProductList();

for(Product product : products){
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    checkBox.setText(product.description);
    linearLayout.addView(checkBox);
}
```

The check list is ok.
My app uses google material design light but the checkboxes are being created with android default theme and i couldn't any reference to views being created like this.

How do I set the app default theme to those views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default they will follow your app theme which defined in your `manifest`  for `pre-lollipop` tinting will work on `AppCompatCheckBox` so instead of using `Checkbox` use `AppCompatCheckBox`
**Edit:**

```
LayoutParams param = new LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT,WRAP_CONTENT);
checkbox.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Hi. I tried replacing CheckBox for AppCompatCheckBox as you said, but now its showing only the item description without the box.